# If statement problems Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am building a simple calculator, and am wondering why my if statement is not working. Can anyone help?

Code:

```batch
title Addition
color a
@echo off
cls
:add
cls
echo What would you like to do?
echo [1]Set first number [2]Set second number [3]Add 1 and 2 [4]Quit [5]Main Menu
set /p act=
if act==1 then goto :1
if act==2 then goto :2
if act==3 then goto :num
if act==4 then goto :quit
if act==5 then goto :menu
:1
cls
echo What is your first number?
set /p 1=
cls
goto :add
:2
cls
echo What is your second number?
set /p 2=
cls
goto :add
:num
num=1+2
echo Your number is %num%
pause
cls
goto :add
:quit
:menu
SimpleCalulator.bat
```

Comment: And what does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of a variable, you need to surround it with `%` (or `!` when using delayed expansion).  You also need to quote your variables unless you really have a good reason not to.  Also, "then" is not a batch-file keyword.

```
if "%act%"=="1" goto :1
if "%act%"=="2" goto :2
if "%act%"=="3" goto :num
if "%act%"=="4" goto :quit
if "%act%"=="5" goto :menu
REM Don't forget to handle unexpected user input:
goto :add
```